# SQL query to get pending rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

**BasicDetails**

```
+----+---------------------+
| DocumentId  | DocumentNo |
+----+---------------------+
|  1          |  100       |
+----+---------------------+
```

**LineItems**

```
+----+--------+------------+
| Id | ItemNo | DocumentId |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |   4001 |          1 |
|  2 |   4002 |          1 |
|  3 |   4003 |          1 |
|  4 |   4004 |          1 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

**PickList**

```
+----+------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+
| Id | DocumentNo | ReservationNo | ItemNo | StatusId | PickListNo |
+----+------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+
|  1 |        100 |           100 |   4001 |        1 |    0000001 |
|  2 |        100 |           100 |   4002 |        2 |    0000001 |
|  3 |        100 |           100 |   4001 |        2 |    0000002 |
|  4 |        100 |           100 |   4003 |        2 |    0000002 |
+----+------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+
```

**Desired Result:**

```
+----+------------+----------------+
| Id | DocumentNo | LineItemCount  |
+----+------------+----------------+
|  1 |        100 |              3 |
+----+------------+----------------+
```

Basic details in the master table. For one entry in BasicDetails there could be multiple LineItems.

ItemNo is unique in lineItem.

There could be multiple pickList for BasicDetails. 
Eg:
`DocumentNo 100 here has two pickLists 0000001 and 0000002`

There could be same itemno in 0000001 and 0000002 but there can not be duplicate itemno for same picklist.

**PickList Scenario 2:**

```
+----+------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+
| Id | DocumentNo | ReservationNo | ItemNo | StatusId | PickListNo |
+----+------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+
|  1 |        100 |           100 |   4001 |        2 |    0000001 |
|  2 |        100 |           100 |   4002 |        2 |    0000001 |
|  3 |        100 |           100 |   4001 |        2 |    0000002 |
|  4 |        100 |           100 |   4003 |        2 |    0000002 |
+----+------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+
```

**Desired result :**

```
+----+------------+----------------+
| Id | DocumentNo | LineItemCount  |
+----+------------+----------------+
|  1 |        100 |              4 |
+----+------------+----------------+
```

**PickList Scenario 3:**

```
+----+------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+
| Id | DocumentNo | ReservationNo | ItemNo | StatusId | PickListNo |
+----+------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+
|  1 |        100 |           100 |   4001 |        1 |    0000001 |
|  2 |        100 |           100 |   4002 |        2 |    0000001 |
|  3 |        100 |           100 |   4001 |        1 |    0000002 |
|  4 |        100 |           100 |   4003 |        2 |    0000002 |
+----+------------+---------------+--------+----------+------------+
```

Desired result would be :

```
+----+------------+----------------+
| Id | DocumentNo | LineItemCount  |
+----+------------+----------------+
|  1 |        100 |              3 |
+----+------------+----------------+
```

My query:

```
   select b.documentid,b.documentno,count(l.id) cnt
   from basicdetails b left join lineitems l on b.documentid= l.documentid
   left join picklist p on l.itemno =p.itemno where p.statusid=1
   group by  b.documentid,b.documentno
```

Comment: What is your question ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Cid its very difficult for me to explain in words. Which is why I have given multiple scenarios. There are 4 different itemno in lineitems for documentno 100 
namely.. 4001,4002,4003,4004. Out of which if in picklist 4001 is marked 1  it means that now we have only 3 itemno left for  doucmentno 100. If 4001 and 4002 both were 1 then itemno count would have been 2.  Duplicate 4001 in picklist are counted as one 4001

Comment: Hi @SamuraiJack please can you explain scenario 3 where you have LineItemCount   = 3 ? Thanks!

Comment: The output here makes no sense at all. There are some business rules that you are not sharing or at least they are not clear at all. The count you are getting contradicts the explanation you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you need but this is so far:

```
select b.documentid
       , b.documentno
       , (select count(*) from PickList) - (select count(*) 
                                            from PickList pn1
                                            where pn1.StatusId = 1)
from BasicDetails b 
left join LineItems l on b.DocumentId = l.DocumentId
left join PickList p on l.ItemNo = p.ItemNo 
where p.StatusId = case when (select count(*) cnt_all 
                              from PickList pn
                              where pn.StatusId = 1) = 0 then 2
                        else 1
                   end
group by  b.documentid
          , b.documentno ;
```

DEMO: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=797817d75bda9d81bbebcf43d584564a

If I understood info from the comments this would then be correct:

```
select b.documentid
       , b.documentno
       , case when (select count(*) cnt_all 
                    from PickList pn
                    where pn.StatusId = 1) = 0
              then (select count(*) cnt_all
                    from LineItems)
              else (select count(*) cnt_all
                    from LineItems) -count(distinct l.id)
         end cnt
from BasicDetails b 
left join LineItems l on b.DocumentId = l.DocumentId
left join PickList p on l.ItemNo = p.ItemNo
where p.StatusId = case when (select count(*) cnt_all 
                              from PickList pn
                              where pn.StatusId = 1) = 0 then 2
                        else 1
                   end
group by  b.documentid
          , b.documentno;
```

DEMO 2 : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=233e5ef14a2b6aaa45ec509872f240c9

Comment: what's 0060105254?

Comment: Hi @SamuraiJack I am sorry, I do not understand. Where ? Also, please do answer my question from above?

Comment: Oh  I am sorry. I pasted wrong value. I meant what's "cnt_all" but now I get it that it's just an alias to count(*).  I have not tested it on my work computer but your answer seems to be the correct answer. It will take me some time to wrap my head around your query though.

Comment: btw I need count of lineitems. Not picklist. I mean if there are zero records in picklist then  count for 100 will be 4 here. Since there there are 4 lineitems. I should have included this in my question

Comment: Hi @SamuraiJack, I have added another query so you can check that too. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @SamuraiJack, so, does any of this query's help ? Cheers!

Comment: Umm the https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4053cbee9cc9b576918dbaff3aa972ad  produces no records. AIt does not meet the condition in my previous comment : " if there are zero records in picklist then count for 100 will be 4 here."

Comment: Hi @SamuraiJack please check the data I have in fiddle. They are all status 1 in PickList , and there ia also a record with 4004 in there...

Comment: Check this one. It has status 2 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1a90b481a5f1bba604abbff43319709c

Comment: Hi @SamuraiJack please check: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=347c93f8aa5edcb9654137fa32d9c83a